# What's the best way in elisp to trap an error case

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm trying to augment the etags-select functions so it will fall-back to a normal find-tag if find-tag at point failed. The code I've tried is:

```
(defun my-etags-find-tag ()
  "Find at point or fall back"
  (interactive)
  (unless (etags-select-find-tag-at-point)
    (etags-select-find-tag)))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-f") 'my-etags-find-tag)
```

However this fails when *point* is not at a valid tag. Instead I get a error thrown by etags-select-find-tag-at-point:

```
etags-select-find-tag-at-point: Wrong type argument: char-or-string-p, nil
```

In this case I just have to repeat the test done by *etags-select-find-tag-at-point*:

```
(defun my-etags-find-tag ()
  "Find at point or fall back"
  (interactive)
  (if (find-tag-default)
      (etags-select-find-tag-at-point)
    (etags-select-find-tag)))
```

But it does seem a little redundant. Is it possible to trap exceptions and do alternate processing in elisp?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try `ignore-errors`; eg,

```
(unless (ignore-errors (etags-select-find-tag-at-point))
  (etags-select-find-tag))
```

Normally, `(ignore-errors body)` returns whatever `body` returns; when there's error, it returns `nil`.

Also look at `condition-case` for more general condition handling.

If you have Elisp info manual installed, you can get more details from
<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>`ignore-errors`.

#### Edit:

I failed to consider the possibility that the function may return nil on success; so we probably need

```
(unless (ignore-errors (or (etags-select-find-tag-at-point) t))
  (etags-select-find-tag))
```

Comment: However ignoring errors don't avoid calling `find-tag-default` twice.

Comment: It also falls through on success. If no error occurs etags-select-find-tag-at-point still returns 'nil and hence the fall through.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer as it answers the question about trapping error cases. However Deigo's answer is still very useful and revelatory.

Answer (score 4):

Without modifying the original source code of `etags-select.el`, I see it the more reasonable option, even when it calls twice to `find-tag-default`. You can cheat the dynamic environment within the call to avoid the repetition of the call by memoizing it with something like:

```
(defun my-etags-find-tag ()
  "Find at point or fall back"
  (interactive)
  (let ((ftd (find-tag-default)))
    (flet ((find-tag-default () ftd))
      (if (find-tag-default)
          (etags-select-find-tag-at-point)
        (etags-select-find-tag)))))
```

**EDIT**: OK, as per your request, an explanation of the code. First, note that this code achieves both questions:

1. It does not fail
2. It is more efficient than the code you show (the one you say it is redundant).

Why is it more efficient? The problem with your redundant code is that you call `find-tag-default` to see if it is `nil`, and, if it is, you call `etags-select-find-tag-at-point`. This function calls again to `find-tag-default` to obtain a default value. What my code does is to cache the value of `find-tag-default` by redefining the function by being just the value you calculated. The `flet` does that, so when `etags-select-find-tag-at-point` calls `find-tag-default`, the calculated value is returned without any further processing.

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to  explain yourself more. I'm not sure I see the benefit of that approach.

Comment: OK, I'll elaborate my answer.